# Duplicate items when consuming ODATA service

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, wcf-data-services

The **WCF/OData webservice**  returns **restful** items of type `vBeheer`.

On client I created the method that consumes:

```
        SRTDBEntities es = new SRTDBEntities(_serviceRoot);
        return es.vBeheer.Where(b => 
            b.TrackID == trackid && 
            b.PersoonID == CurrentPersoon.ID );
```

However I noticed (after an afternoon of debugging) When adding **.ToList()** to the expression, the **resultset goes corrupted**. The `Count()` of the items is correct and as expected, but the values of the items are wrong. Many are **duplicate** and many are **missing** (obviously).

So I tested this in *linqpad*:

```
vBeheer.Where (b => b.TrackID==23 && b.PersoonID == 19   ).Dump();
```

- returns correct results fom the service as expected,  note that **ID
  should be an unique** value per "row":

[image: right]

but when adding .ToList() it goes wrong

```
 vBeheer.Where (b => b.TrackID==23 && b.PersoonID == 19   ).ToList().Dump();
```

this results many duplicate (without any pattern?) items

[image]

This behaviour is unexpected and unwanted. And even more interesting. We determined that the database returns correct results, on debugging the server (in the webservice) the results are still correct, but when arriving on the client, it goes horribly wrong.

IT wouldn't be a problem, but the data is used by a DevExpress Component (DXGrid) that does a ToList() anyway.

nb: executing the query in the browser:

```
http://localhost:52671/SRTDataService.svc/vBeheer()?$filter=TrackID%20eq%2023%20and%20PersoonID%20eq%2019
```

returns an expected set of unique items.

Comment: Can you make that an answer Arnold, I checked it and , after regenerating the edmx, indeed, the keys were changed somehow. I fixed it and it works..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This usually indicates that you're having a view with key columns (in the EF model) that are not unique. EF just repeats the first row it has read with a set of key values.

The difference with and without `ToList()` is unexpected though. It's just a way to enumerate the query, which Linqpad also does when executing `Dump()`.

Comment: This happened during regenerating the edmx. The keys dropped off. I put them back